# What is the difference between two plane waves with positive frequency?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, electrons, frequency

Is it possible to interpret the first plane wave $e^{(ikx-iωt)}$ as an electron and the second plane wave $e^{(-ikx-iωt)}$ as a positron? I ask because they both have positive frequency (energy), but they are still different.

Roger Penrose seems to be talking about something similar when he says: "Now an ordinary wavefunction ψ should have positive frequency, but we can also consider some quantity φ, of the same kind as ψ, but which is of negative frequency. Then the complex conjugate φ⃰, of φ, would be a wavefunction of a different type from ψ, although both φ⃰ and ψ are now of positive frequency. The quantity φ⃰ would provide a wavefunction for a 1-antiparticle state." The Road to Reality, p. 663

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Your first wave is something going to the right, and your second one goes to the left, no?

Comment: The plane waves you have written are just abstract plane waves with opposite wave numbers $k$, you're looking for solutions of the Dirac equation, but the math is a bit more complicated than that

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to interpret this question, those are just exponentials with no context, and are then mathematical objects, not physical objects.

Assuming you're using standard notation, the difference between those two plane waves is that they are travelling in opposite directions in some 1D space.

In terms of elections and positions, depending on your current level of understanding, I'd first start with classical field theory.

I'm not really sure what you're asking for, so that's all I can give you. Perhaps the problem is my comprehension.

Comment: I tried to edit the question, so I hope it already makes more sense.